# Spring Security 3 and Web application session

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to put some vaues or object in session. How can I add these extra information

```
<bean id="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper" class="org.krams.tutorial.security.UserDetailsContextMapperImpl"/>   
    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="in.holcim.net" />
        <!-- <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://10.235.0.164:389" /> -->
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://10.234.12.33:389" />
        <!-- <property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" /> --> 
        <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper"/>       
        <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
        <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" /> 
    </bean>




  public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {

        List<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();



            if("kamahire".equals(username)){
                mappedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthority(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4356967414267942910L;

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        //return "ROLE_KAMLESHA";
                        return "ROLE_USER";
                    } 

                });

            }else if(username.equals("saslanka")){
                mappedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthority(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167156646226168080L;

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        return "ROLE_KAMLESHA";
                    } 

                });


            /*if (granted.getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase("MY USER GROUP")) {
                mappedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthority(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4356967414267942910L;

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        return "ROLE_USER";
                    } 

                });
            } else if(granted.getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase("MY ADMIN GROUP")) {
                mappedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthority() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167156646226168080L;

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        return "ROLE_ADMIN";
                    }
                });
            }*/
        }else{

                mappedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthority(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167156646226168780L;

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        return "ROLE_ADMIN2";
                    }

                });


            }
        System.out.println("User name is :" + username + " ROLE" + mappedAuthorities.get(0).getAuthority() );
        return new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, mappedAuthorities);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails arg0, DirContextAdapter arg1) {
    }


}
```

I want to set session or principal object in above class with extra parameter. How can I add.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `User` object, which is then accessible via

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

or you can use authentication event listeners to further prepare user session.

```
public class MySessionPreparator implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute("foo", "bar", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Paval How can I use above bean MySessionPreparator in Spring security configuration.

Comment: You just define this bean within application context and it will get called automatically after user authenticates. That is the beauty of event handling in Spring.